# Make moving a rectangle (Remove/Reappear) Corona SDK

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, rectangles

### Hi Everyone,

I would like know one thing :

I want to make this rectangle moving from the left side to the right side with physics and loop, and make it disappear when is out the leftscreen, and make reappear it in the right side,

This is what I've made in my code but I would like know if there is another easiest way to do it.

Is it better to use transition.to ?

Ps : My game is an endless runner game where the player jump from the floor to rectangles in the air
if someone have tutorial for this, I get it ! thank you

thanks every one for all

```
    local physics = require( "physics" )
    physics.start()
    physics.setDrawMode( "hybrid")
    local _x = display.contentCenterX
    local _y = display.contentCenterY
    local speed = 10
    local GroupMur1 = display.newGroup()


        local Mur1 = display.newRect(680,25,680,25)
        Mur1.x = _x +900
        Mur1.y = _y +80
        physics.addBody(Mur1, "static")
        GroupMur1:insert(Mur1)

    local a =1
    local function update ()
        if(a==1)then updateMur1() end
        if(a==2)then updateMur2() end
    end

    function updateMur1 ()
    GroupMur1.x =GroupMur1.x - speed
    if(GroupMur1.x < -2000) then
         GroupMur1:remove(1)
         a=2
         end
         end

    function updateMur2()
    GroupMur1:insert(Mur1)
    physics.addBody(Mur1, "static")
    GroupMur1.x = _x + 900
    a=1
         end

    timer.performWithDelay(1, update, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's true that the transition.to is really useful and easy to use, but if you want to use physics, then use the applyLinearImpulse(), which is going to be easier if you want to use also collision detection. And once the rectangle is off screen, use the if and then function. It would be something like this:

```
if object.x > 500 then -- for example with a rectangle of 20 by 20 
object.x = -20
end
```

Comment: remember, if you have the answer, please activate the "answered" button, or show us your answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

To extend what @Fannick said, which should work by the way, the generic way to trigger this (for any object of any size) would be the code below. For this, I assume you have `object.anchorX = 0` or `object:setReferencePoint(display.CenterLeftReferencePoint)` depending on your SDK version (the former is for v2 and the latter is for v1 - [This link](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/migration_g20.html) should help clear up differences)

```
--if the object is past the edge (screenOriginX used to scale for bigger devices)
if object.x > (display.contentWidth - display.screenOriginX) then
    object.x = 0 + display.screenOriginX - object.contentWidth
end
```

If you have `object.anchorX = 0.5` or `object:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)` (or haven't set either - both of these are the defaults) it would be:

```
if object.x > (display.contentWidth + (object.contentWidth/2) - display.screenOriginX) then
    object.x = 0 + display.screenOriginX - (object.contentWidth/2)
end
```

For `object.anchorX = 1` or `object:setReferencePoint(display.CenterRightReferencePoint)` it would be:

```
if object.x > (display.contentWidth + object.contentWidth - display.screenOriginX) then
    object.x = 0 + display.screenOriginX
end
```

Hope you find the answer if you haven't already!

Cush

Answer (score 0):

thanks both of you guy;

I've used the velocity to make the rectangle start to move and a collision to make 'em disappear
All your answers help me to understand better corona SDK !